# @Named annotation in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, annotations, jsr330

Per Spring 3 document, [The IoC container](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-named), the `@Named` annotation is a standard equivalent to the `@Component` annotation.

Since `@Repository`, `@Service`, and `@Controller` are all `@Component`, I tried to used `@Named` for all of them in my Spring MVC application. It works fine. But I found the replacement of `@Controller` seems to have a bug. In the controller class, originally, it was

```
@Controller
public class MyController{
    ...
}
```

It works fine. When I changed `@Controller` to `@Named`

```
@Named
public class MyController{
    ...
}
```

It failed with error:

> "No mapping found for HTTP request with URI ...".

But if I added `@RequestMapping` to the class as follow

```
@Named
@RequestMapping
public class MyController{
     ...
 }
```

It would work as expected.

For `@Repository` and `@Service`, I can simply replace them with `@Named` with no issue. But the replacement of `@Controller` needs extra work. Is there anything I am missing in the configuration?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`@Named` works the same as `@Component`. However, the annotations `@Controller`, `@Service`, and `@Repository` are more specific.

From the Spring [docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-stereotype-annotations):

> `@Component` is a generic stereotype for any Spring-managed component.
>   `@Repository`, `@Service`, and `@Controller` are specializations of
>   `@Component` for more specific use cases, for example, in the
>   persistence, service, and presentation layers, respectively.
>
> For example, these stereotype annotations make ideal targets for
>   pointcuts. It is also possible that `@Repository`, `@Service`, and
>   `@Controller` may carry additional semantics in future releases of the
>   Spring Framework. Thus, if you are choosing between using `@Component`
>   or `@Service` for your service layer, `@Service` is clearly the better
>   choice. Similarly, as stated above, `@Repository` is already supported
>   as a marker for automatic exception translation in your persistence
>   layer.

[This](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-standard-annotations) section explains the difference with `@Named`.

Many components, like Spring's `DispatcherServlet` (MVC configuration in `WebApplicationContext`) aren't looking for `Component`, they are looking for `@Controller`. So when it scans your class, it won't find it in `@Named`. In a similar fashion, transaction management with `@Transactional` looks for `@Service` and `@Repository`, not for the more generic `@Component`.

Comment: Does it mean I can safely use `@Named` to replace `@Component` for generic bean injection, but I still need to use `@Repository`, `@Service`, and `@Controller` in Spring MVC specific features?

Comment: @dino You are welcome. Consider accepting this answer unless you want to wait for more answers with other details.

Answer (score 4):

All `@Repository`, `@Service` and `@Controller` are mainly for declaring Spring beans, apart from that it gives extra information to Spring about the type of bean like controller, dao etc