# Difference between @Bean and @Named

Tags: java, spring

I'm working on a class that has the following:

```
@Bean(name = "pluto")
public Z potato (...) {
    ...
}

@Bean(name = "mars") 
public carrot (@Named("pluto") Z z) {
    ...
}
```

I'd like to know if `@Bean` and `@Named` are interchangeable.

Also, why is `@Named` being used in the parameter?

@Makoto, [@Named annotation in Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18540696/named-annotation-in-spring-mvc) is similar but the answer here seems to be

> `@Named` and `@Bean` are equivalent, but are from different APIs. So only use
>   `@Named` for consistency

Comment: they are annotations from different APIs. I'd use the Spring's `@Qualifier` instead of `@Named` to be consistent and follow one style.

Comment: So, I should be able to replace `@Bean` with `@Named` in this entire class?

Comment: if Spring treats them the same, yes, you can