# Do I need the @Named annotation for an inner class

Tags: java, annotations, inject

I'm new to annotations and am wondering if I need the @Named annotation for my Bar class. I've googled some but still don't know if the annoation is needed for this inner class.

```
public abstract class Foo{
         //code
     @Named
     @Configuration
     class Bar{
         //code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In vanilla `javax.inject.Named`, [as per docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Named.html), the annotation is intended to define a `String based qualifier`. If you don't intend to provide a qualifier, you don't need to put the annotation. :-)

In [Spring though](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-named), the docs state that you can provide a `@Named` annotation without a value, with the same practical effect of using `@Component`. I wouldn't recommend that as the code looks misleading.

Comment: forgot to mention I'm using spring as well. So the way it was explained to me in that context is that @Named in spring will still work on classes without a qualifier. Not sure if this changes the answer at all.

Comment: @JohnEarl as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18540696/named-annotation-in-spring-mvc it seems that you can indeed use it, without a qualifier, instead of `@Component`.

Comment: Updated the answer with the spring information we discovered

Comment: Thanks, very helpful answer.